# Html font-size is not overriden

Tags: html, css, font-size

I need to add some style to affect the whole html text size by a percentage. With the following I could only change the text with default font size but not those with fixed text size.

My html:

```
<style type="text/css">body{font-size:300%;}</style>
<body>
The <font style="color:#ff0000">company has been a </font>long way<strike> in the most part</strike> of a good <u>idea tying </u>I was <b>wondering</b> if you <font style="font-size:20px">are not the</font> intended <font style="background-color:#00ff00">recipient</font> of the <i>most</i> important <font style="color:#ffbf00">thing</font> 
</body>
```

The sentense "are not the" is not affected since it's given it's own font-size `20px`. What's wanted is to be multiplied by 3 (the 300% in the first line).

Comment: Before it starts raining downvotes. Add a fiddle to make your problem clear to others...

Comment: I made one: https://jsfiddle.net/u1tkh5bd/

Comment: `<font>` is obsolete, don't use it. And `font-size` doesn't work like this. If you want relative units, use `em` instead of `px`.

Comment: Just change your font tags into span's https://jsfiddle.net/u1tkh5bd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS and inline calls are working exactly as expected.

The CSS on the `body` is overwritten by an inline piece of CSS which takes priority over it.

`300%` is a value, not a multiplier.

```css
body {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
The <font style="color:#ff0000">company has been a </font>long way<strike> in the most part</strike> of a good <u>idea tying </u>I was <b>wondering</b> if you 
<font style="font-size:20px">are not the</font> 
intended <font style="background-color:#00ff00">recipient</font> of the <i>most</i> important <font style="color:#ffbf00">thing</font>
```

---

One alternative could be to use the CSS3 `calc()` function where you can specify you want the value `20px` multiplied by 3.

```css
body {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
The <font style="color:#ff0000">company has been a </font>long way<strike> in the most part</strike> of a good <u>idea tying </u>I was <b>wondering</b> if you 
<font style="font-size: calc(20px * 3)">are not the</font> 
intended <font style="background-color:#00ff00">recipient</font> of the <i>most</i> important <font style="color:#ffbf00">thing</font>
```